# How to create bean of JpaRepository

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have interface:

```
@Repository
public interface EmpoleyeeRepository extends
        HumanRepository<Employee, Long> {
}

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface HumanRepository<T, ID> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {}
```

and my class:

```
    public  class EmployeeClassWithRepositor {

        @Autowired
        private EmpoleyeeRepository employeeRepository;

        EmployeeClassWithRepositor() {
           Optional<Employee> employee = employeeRepository.findById(1L);
        }

}
```

But this repository is actually null.. How can I wired it with this class? Ewentually create proper bean of JpaRepository (I don't want to create class with implement this interface repo)

Comment: Is your EmployeeClassWithRepository a managed bean?

Comment: No it isn't I am new with spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion:

It looks like you are trying to implement Active record pattern (each entity is responsible for persisting itself) by both wrapping Jpa entity and injecting repository to your domain object.

This is very rarely practiced in Spring.
Instead, create a service class annotated with @Service.
Inject your repository class there.
Call your repository methods to obtain entities.

Spring injects objects only to managed beans.
Your EmployeeWithRepositori is not managed, so nothing gets injected